# Worksheet_Calculate repeats until I force quit Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working VBA script that generates an Outlook email when cell value = 1. This runs on a hidden worksheet (cell is changed to 1 when criteria is met on visible summary worksheet).

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
    'Update by Extendoffice 2019/8/2
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("AA1"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 1 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello " & Range("G2") & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please review the following list of loan documents that were produced through our online system from " & Range("A2") & ". Your total bill for this month's documents is " & FormatCurrency(Range("E2")) & " (" & Range("C2") & " x " & Range("D2") & "):" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F2") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F3") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F4") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F5") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F6") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F7") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F8") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F9") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F10") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F11") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F12") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F13") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F14") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F15") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F16") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F17") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F18") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F19") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F19") & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F20") & "   " & Range("F21") & "   " & Range("F22") & "   " & Range("F23") & "   " & Range("F24") & "   " & Range("F25") & "   " & Range("F26") & "   " & Range("F27") & "   " & Range("F28") & "   " & Range("F29") & "   " & Range("F30") & "   " & Range("F31") & "   " & Range("F32") & "   " & Range("F33") & "   " & Range("F34") & "   " & Range("F35") & "   " & Range("F36") & "   " & Range("F37") & "   " & Range("F38") & "   " & Range("F39") & "   " & Range("F40") & "   " & Range("F41") & "   " & Range("F42") & "   " & Range("F43") & "   " & Range("F44") & "   " & Range("F45") & "   " & Range("F46") & "   " & Range("F47") & "   " & Range("F48") & "   " & Range("F49") & "   " & Range("F50") & "   " & Range("F51") & "   " & Range("F52") & "   " & Range("F53") & "   " & Range("F54") & "   " & vbNewLine & _
    Range("F55") & "   " & Range("F56") & "   " & Range("F57") & "   " & Range("F58") & "   " & Range("F59") & "   " & Range("F60") & "   " & Range("F61") & "   " & Range("F62") & "   " & Range("F63") & "   " & Range("F64") & "   " & Range("F65") & "   " & Range("F66") & "   " & Range("F67") & "   " & Range("F68") & "   " & Range("F69") & "   " & Range("F70") & "   " & Range("F71") & "   " & Range("F72") & "   " & Range("F73") & "   " & Range("F74") & "   " & Range("F75") & "   " & Range("F76") & "   " & Range("F77") & "   " & Range("F78") & "   " & Range("F79") & "   " & Range("F80") & "   " & Range("F81") & "   " & Range("F82") & "   " & Range("F83") & "   " & Range("F84") & "   " & Range("F85") & "   " & Range("F86") & "   " & Range("F87") & "   " & Range("F88") & "   " & Range("F89") & "  " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please let us know within two business days whether your records match ours. If we do not get a response within this time frame, we will invoice you shortly thereafter. If your credit card is on file and we have a pre-existing authorization, we will charge your card on file and provide you with a copy of your paid invoice." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Thank you!" & vbNewLine
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
    .To = Range("H2")
    .CC = "billing@example.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("B2") & " - (ID: " & Range("I2") & ") - " & Range("A2") & " Lightning Docs Usage & Billing"
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim xI As Integer
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Range("AA1")
    On Error GoTo Err01
    xI = Int(xRg.Value)
    If xI = 1 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
    Err01:
End Sub
```

This is a bodge way of adding what should be a table into the email body.

I recently discovered Ron de Bruin's script for converting a table to HTML and adding it to an email body that way. I got the script running, but my problem comes when trying to trigger the macro from another worksheet. The user will be on the summary worksheet and make a change to cause cell AA1 on the VBA script worksheet to change to 1.

Without `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`, it works when I am on the worksheet with the script.
When I add `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`, it can be triggered from a different worksheet, but it gets stuck at the point where a temporary worksheet is created, and keeps creating temporary worksheets until I force quit Excel.

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("AA1"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
    .To = Range("H2")
    .CC = "billing@example.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("C2") & " - (ID: " & Range("I2") & ") - " & Range("B2") & " Lightning Docs Usage & Billing"
    .HTMLBody = "<font size=-0> Hello " & Range("G2") & ",<br/><br/>" & 
    "Please review the following list of loan documents that were produced through our online system from " & Range("B2") & ". <br/>Your total bill for this month's documents is " & FormatCurrency(Range("F2")) & " (" & Range("E2") & " x " & FormatCurrency(Range("D2")) & "):</font>" & 
    RangetoHTML(Range("Table3_2[Titles]")) & 
    "<br/><font size=-0>Please let us know within two business days whether your records match ours. If we do not get a response within this time frame, we will invoice you shortly thereafter. If your credit card is on file and we have a pre-existing authorization, we will charge your card on file and provide you with a copy of your paid invoice." & 
    "<br/><br/>Thank you!</font><br/>"
    .Display 'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim xI As Integer
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Range("AA1")
    On Error GoTo Err01
    xI = Int(xRg.Value)
    If xI = 1 Then
    Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
    Err01:
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should turn off events: `Application.EnableEvents = False`, or turn off calculation: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, and then turn them back on at the end.

Comment: Wow.  Added `Application.EnableEvents = False` to start of sub then turned it back on again as you suggested, and it works!  That was some speedy problem solving, thanks BigBen!

Comment: You probably want an error handler too: `On Error GoTo Handler`, then add `Handler:` on the line before `Application.EnableEvents = True`, so that in case of an error, events still get turned back on.

Comment: Nice, have added - thanks!